# Keep HTML header only for home page

Tags: html, css, hugo

I am customizing a hugo theme. Every page shows the same header background image.

I want to show the header image only on the HOME page not on the other pages.

Here is the css snip

```
#head {
  background: #f4f4f4 url(../images/bg_head.jpg) top center;
  background-size: cover; /* auto - contain - cover - orig is cover*/
  color: #7C7C7C;
  padding: 30px 0 35px 0;
  height: 300px;          /* added to reduce the height of the banner - wasn't there */
}
#head img.img-circle {
  display: block;
  width: 100px; /* orig 140px */
  height: 100px; /* orig 140px */
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 9px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Looked at the suggested URL, doesn't answer my question. I am asking if I can control the behavior from css? Just like I can control the height and location of the banner. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is no. You need JS unless you can add `#head { display: block }` on the homepage and have  `#head { display: none }` before that on all pages